# Why chrome 34.0.1847.137 crash my os x 10.9.3?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, crash

Chrome crashes my 13" and 15" rMBP.

> I got to press the power button to reboot to solve it.

The shutdown monitor log and chrome://crashes is empty, so I check the system log.

```
5/17/14 16:12:45.946 Google Chrome[306]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x1b559efe
5/17/14 16:12:46.066 Google Chrome[306]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x1b559efe
5/17/14 16:13:57.443 Google Chrome Helper[4105]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
5/17/14 16:13:57.443 Google Chrome Helper[4105]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
5/17/14 16:13:58.361 Google Chrome Helper[4105]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
5/17/14 16:13:58.361 Google Chrome Helper[4105]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
5/17/14 16:14:27.394 Google Chrome Helper[4105]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
5/17/14 16:14:27.394 Google Chrome Helper[4105]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
5/17/14 16:14:30.231 Google Chrome Helper[4105]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
5/17/14 16:14:30.231 Google Chrome Helper[4105]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
5/17/14 16:15:04.180 loginwindow[78]: magsafeStateChanged state changed old 1 new 2
5/17/14 16:15:21.030 loginwindow[78]: magsafeStateChanged state changed old 2 new 1
5/17/14 16:15:34.039 SophosWebD[99]: <SMENode: 0x7f9af3e09c70> localNode csc:1ERROR! encountered an error while writing to outputstream| error:Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=32 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Broken pipe"
5/17/14 16:15:35.099 Google Chrome Helper[4105]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
5/17/14 16:15:35.099 Google Chrome Helper[4105]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
5/17/14 16:16:37.447 Google Chrome Helper[4105]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
5/17/14 16:16:37.447 Google Chrome Helper[4105]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
```

Chrome Version:34.0.1847.137
extensions:
Google Docs 0.6
OneTab 1.6
Pocket (formerly Read It Later) 1.7.1
plugins:
QuickTime Player - Version: 7.7.3
Widevine Content Decryption Module - Version: 1.4.2.464
Adobe Flash Player (2 files) - Version: 13.0.0.214
PPAPI (out-of-process)
OS X:10.9.3

Is there anyone else got the same problem?

Comment: that does not show the Chrome doing it?

Comment: if you disable extensions/plugins one by one that could  show who is doing it

Comment: Re-install chrome and disable plugins in addition to @Buscar웃

Comment: Look in the Console for the tab called "CrashReporter" yes it is one word.. and publish it here

Comment: How exactly does the computer crash?

Comment: The only way to solve this crash is to press power button and reboot it.

Comment: but it happens no matter how many tabs I opened

Comment: I don't have CrashReporter on sidebar.

Comment: So it was not a Crash, the system locked up. Next time that happens note the time before reboot. After reboot go to Console to the time stamp and copy 30 lines before it happened, and 10 lines after.

Comment: How to call it? This situation only occur when I use chrome.

Comment: May 17 16:26:02 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1400315162 0

Comment: May 17 16:26:03 localhost syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice:
 ASL Module "com.apple.appstore" claims selected messages.
 Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.

Comment: A friend's 15" MBP is having the same issue: When Google Chrome is opened, the screen will either go black, or be covered in hash lines as if the graphics card is dying or the monitor cable is frayed. OP: Is this the same thing you experience?

Comment: @user3467070 Maybe you're out of memory/disk?

Comment: I had similar issue and reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=523559), but I'm not sure if related.

Answer (score -1):

I also have Sophos installed. Maybe that breaks internet access? Edit: Seems to be the case. Have a look here: [Sophos Website](http://openforum.sophos.com/t5/Sophos-Anti-Virus-for-Mac-Home/Sophos-9-causes-Mavericks-to-freeze/td-p/14893/page/2)

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.